# Can't get import to be recognized - jsonpickle

Tags: python, jsonpickle

I am using PyDev via eclipse and have used easy_install to get jsonpickle.  No matter what I do I can't seem to get the import to work.

What I have tried thus far:

- I have removed it from easy_install.pth and deleted the egg and installed again.
- Add my python lib, dll, etc folders to a  PYTHONPATH system variable
- Restarted eclipse

Other imports are working fine.  Not sure what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Sorry should have included OS / Python version.
OS: Windows 7
Python: 2.7

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS and python version?

1. Please use pip.  Always.
2. pydev seems to ignore your package.  It should be in /usr/share/pythonX.Y/site-packages/jsonpickle, or, if on Windows, c:\pythonxx[...].
3. If using Linux, please try to find a distro package for jsonpickle.

Comment: Edited initial question OS = Windows 7, Python Version = 2.7

Comment: I see the package in site-packages and it is also in my easy_install.pth file

Comment: Yeah it did...must have had something wrong with my original install via easy_install